# jQuery - how to prevent html from hiding element?

Tags: jquery

I have a ul li sublist with toggle.

```
ul
   li a.trigger
       ul.sub_list li
   li
   li
```

Event - click.

When I click the `a.trigger`, `ul.sub_list` will show.
To hide `ul.sub_list`. I need to click the `a.trigger` or html element.

The problem is how to stop html from `hide()` `ul.sub_list` when user click `ul.sub_list` items.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zYgfr/

this is like facebook notification.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zYgfr/1/ updated once check the fiddle.

Comment: thanks, but it does not hide ul.sub_list when i click other area than ul.sub_list(other html area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
$(".sub_list a").click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The concept is that, by default, when an element is clicked, it propagates up through the DOM.

So when the link is clicked, eventually after propagation to each parent, the event will reach the HTML root element, triggering any event handlers along its path.

To stop that, we call event.stopPropagation().

Comment: Or even better on the `.sub_list li` so it doesn't disappear on any click around the notification area

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:
http://jsfiddle.net/zYgfr/4/